# Modified parameter name with variable in Python

Tags: php, python, mysql

I'm translating PHP code to Python code which inserts data into a MySql table.

There are four possible columns based on a naming convention:
image_ + [hq,sq, lq, thumb] + _url

The php code is as follows (using Laravel DB Query):

```
DB::table('items')
                ->insertGetId(array(
                   'title' => $title,
                    'image_' . $quality . '_url' => $amazon_url,
                ));
```

The corresponding python code (using SqlAlchemy Core) which is giving me a syntax error:

```
item_ins = items_tbl.insert().values(title=item_title, 
                                                   image_+quality+_url=amazon_url

            )
```

How can I accomplish the same result in Python without reverting to if/else statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have variably named keyword arguments in a Python function call. However, you can expand a `dict` into keyword arguments:

```
item_ins = items_tbl.insert().values(**{'title' : item_title,
                                        'image_'+quality+'_url' : amazon_url})
```

If `quality=='hq'` for example, this is equivalent to calling

```
item_ins = items_tbl.insert().values(title = item_title,
                                     image_hq_url: amazon_url)
```

You should also note that in the syntax you tried to use, you tried to treat `image_` and `_url` as string literals and `quality` as a variable, without making any syntactic distinction between them. There's no way that would work.